# How can I get list items in SharePoint using REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I used this synthax to get list Items

```
http://server/site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items
```

I get a list repeating today's date but not items of the list

[repeating date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QRnb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Seems like your feed reading view is ON. You will have to turn it OFF.**

Please follow below steps

1. Open IE >> GoTo Tools >> Internet Options
2. GoTo Content Tab

[image]

3. Click on Settings in front of "Feeds and Web Slices"
4. **Unmark** the check box of "turn on feed reading view"

[image]

5. OK..Ok
6. Restart IE and test the URL again.